# Passing data from one template using a click event on another template

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm starting with meteor and wondering how someone would do something like this.

I have lots of tasks listed out each one representing a single item in a collection.

I also have a single `form template` that is rendered elsewhere on the screen, when someone clicks on the task I would like the form to populate so that people can edit the data fields.

How do I go about passing the `tasks data`, from a click event on the task template to the form which is in a completely separate template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Sessions](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/session). 
In your list item template:

```
Template.yourItem.events({
  'click .something': function() {
    Session.set('selectedItem', this._id);
  }
});
```

In your form template create a helper to retrieve the list item data:

```
Template.yourForm.helpers({
  selectedItemData: function() {
    return ItemsCollection.findOne({_id: Session.get('selectedItem')});
  }
});
```

Then just use your helper to populate your form using `with` for example:

```
{{#with selectedItemData}}
  <form>
    ...
    <input type="text" value="{{yourfield}}">
    ...
  </form>
{{/with}}
```

Comment: Thanks @Guillaume. What if we do not want to use Sessions as they are global and may not be suitable to use across large applications. Is there some way in Meteor to define Reactive Variable that is accessible across templates. Here is one good article that explains the approach but that is limited to one instance of template not across templates - https://medium.com/@Dominus/meteor-tips-and-workarounds-b791151ce870

Comment: That's the purpose of reactive variables, to be accessible only in a template instance. Apart from that and session variables, I don't think there is something else especially accessible in multiple instances but not globally